# How to construct irreducible representations of supergroup $SU(N|N)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematics, superalgebra

In physics, it is quite common to use Young tableaux to denote the irreducible representations of Lie groups, such as $SU(N)$. There are many excellent textbooks explaining how to construct them.
Similarly, are there any good references (understandable for ordinary physicists who had studied lie algebra) explaining the general recipe on how to construct irreducible representations of Lie supergroup such as $SU(N|N)$?
(Here $SU(N|N)$ is the supergroup containing the usual Lie group $SU(N) \times SU(N)$, where the first $SU(N)$ is the bosonic part and the second $SU(N)$ is the fermionic part.)

Comment: Try beating $SU(2|2)$, which you must have studied, to death, first... Did [Balatenkin & Bars, 1981](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.525127) confuse you?

Answer (score 0):

Please see a paper "SU(2|2) and five dimensional supergravities" in Modern Physics Letters A (1988) 1005-1011

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417984)

Comment: doi:[10.1142/S0217732388001185](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217732388001185) is usually stable for linking.

Comment: @AlexNelson, still I believe that this post does not constitute an answer to the question. We don't even know what is in the paper (which is not even linked, it is just mentioned). It may, or may not provide a solution to the question. I am voting to delete this answer as, in my opinion, is not an answer, it is just a recommendation, which is more suitable to be a comment.